# Why git has 2 things Account > username and Profile > name

Tags: git, github

I got new computer and trying to setup git on it , while doing that got this question.

I did google but didn't find exact reason what is the difference between

Account > username and Profile > name

Why there are 2 different things ?

Per my understanding git looks for one of the emails as primary key.

Please clarify

thanks & regards,
Vikram

Comment: Not sure for a valid query , why somebody will give down voting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git (as any other VCS) have two independent layers

- Authorization
- Presentation

At authorization layer you have to provide (some) credential in order to get access to repository

At presentation layer you define how you'll be visible in history of repository

Comment: Per my understanding email links to Authorization layer.  Why does Git has username and name linking to Presentation layer ?